# On the surface area of a set

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I have a question about an estimate of the surface area of a set.

Let $B(r)$ denotes the open ball of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ centered at origin with radius $r>0$. Let $F:\mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function and define 
\begin{equation}
\text{Lip}(F)=\inf\{L>0:|F(x)-F(y)| \le L|x-y|,x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \}.
\end{equation}

**Question**

Define $B^{\ast}(r)=F(B(r))$. I want to obtain an upper estimate of $\sigma(B^{\ast}(r))$, where $\sigma(B^{\ast}(r))$ is the surface area of $B^{\ast}(r)$. Strictly speaking, $\sigma(B^{\ast}(r))$ is the $d-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure of $\partial B^{\ast}(r)$. That is, $\sigma(B^{\ast}(r))=\mathcal{H}^{d-1}(\partial B^{\ast}(r))$.

**My attempt**

It is known that the following inequality:
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{H}^{d-1}(F(E)) \le \text{Lip}(F)^{d-1}\mathcal{H}^{d-1}(E), 
\end{equation*}
for all $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

**But can we show $\partial B^{\ast}(r) \subset F \bigl( \partial B(r) \bigr)$ (if necessary, we may assume $F$ is smooth)?** If this is true, we have
\begin{align*}
\sigma(B^{\ast}(r))&=\mathcal{H}^{d-1}(\partial B^{\ast}(r)) \\
& \le \text{Lip}(F)^{d-1}\mathcal{H}^{d-1}(\partial B(r))\\
&= \text{Lip}(F)^{d-1}\sigma( B(r)).
\end{align*}

**Can we have an upper estimate like as 
$
\sigma(B^{\ast}(r))
 \le Cr^{d-1} ?
$**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In addition to what Mikhail Katz said, see for example this duplicate : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917494/image-of-boundary-of-continuous-open-function. Furthermore, while $\partial B^\ast(r)$ is $(d-1)$-rectifiable and has finite $\mathcal{H}^{d-1}$ measure, I don't know why you should have the same decay with $r^{d-1}$.

Comment: Could you please show me a reference for the inequality

\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{H}^{d-1}(F(E)) \le \text{Lip}(F)^{d-1}\mathcal{H}^{d-1}(E), 
\end{equation*}?

Comment: Please see Section 2.4.1 in this book: https://www.crcpress.com/Measure-Theory-and-Fine-Properties-of-Functions/Evans-Gariepy/p/book/9780849371578.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to assume that the boundary of the image is contained in the image of the boundary, even in the case $n=1$; consider for example the function $y=x^2$ on $[-1,1]$.